# RectForMapRect MonoTouch.UIKit.UIKitThreadAccessException

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios, thread-safety, mapkit

I have this issue only in MonoTouch 5.4. DrawMapRect is multithreaded, but I need to use RectForMapRect here. Can I do it without InvokeOnMainThread?

Error:

```
MonoTouch.UIKit.UIKitThreadAccessException: UIKit Consistency error: you are calling a UIKit method that can only be invoked from the UI thread.
  at MonoTouch.UIKit.UIApplication.EnsureUIThread () [0x00019] in /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/monotouch/src/UIKit/UIApplication.cs:49
  at MonoTouch.MapKit.MKOverlayView.RectForMapRect (MKMapRect mapRect) [0x00000] in /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/monotouch/src/MapKit/MKOverlayView.g.cs:146
  at MapTest.MyMKOverlayView.DrawMapRect (MKMapRect mapRect, Single zoomScale, MonoTouch.CoreGraphics.CGContext context) [0x00009] in /Users/kirill/Desktop/MapTest/MapTest/MapTestViewController.cs:38
```

Source code here:

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;

using MonoTouch.Foundation;
using MonoTouch.UIKit;
using MonoTouch.MapKit;

namespace MapTest
{
    public class MyMKMapView : MKMapView
    {
        public MyMKMapView(RectangleF frame) : base(frame)
        {
            GetViewForOverlay = GetViewForOverlayImp;
        }

        private MKOverlayView GetViewForOverlayImp(MKMapView mapView, NSObject overlay)
        {
            return new MyMKOverlayView();
        }

        public void AddNewOverlay()
        {
            AddOverlay(new MyMKOverlay());
        }
    }

    public class MyMKOverlayView : MKOverlayView
    {
        public MyMKOverlayView() : base()
        {

        }

        public override void DrawMapRect(MKMapRect mapRect, float zoomScale, MonoTouch.CoreGraphics.CGContext context)
        {
            base.DrawMapRect(mapRect, zoomScale, context);
            RectForMapRect(new MKMapRect());
        }
    }

    public class MyMKOverlay : MKOverlay
    {
        public override MKMapRect BoundingMapRect
        {
            get
            {
                return new MKMapRect(10 , 10 , 10 , 10);
            }
        }

        public MyMKOverlay() : base()
        {

        }
    }

    public partial class MapTestViewController : UIViewController
    {
        private MyMKMapView _map;

        public MapTestViewController() : base ("MapTestViewController", null)
        {
            _map = new MyMKMapView(View.Bounds);
            View.AddSubview(_map);
        }

        public override void DidReceiveMemoryWarning()
        {
            // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
            base.DidReceiveMemoryWarning();

            // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
        }

        public override void ViewDidLoad()
        {
            base.ViewDidLoad();
            // Perform any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        }

        public override void ViewDidUnload()
        {
            base.ViewDidUnload();

            // Clear any references to subviews of the main view in order to
            // allow the Garbage Collector to collect them sooner.
            //
            // e.g. myOutlet.Dispose (); myOutlet = null;

            ReleaseDesignerOutlets();
        }

        public override void ViewDidAppear(bool animated)
        {
            base.ViewDidAppear(animated);
            _map.AddNewOverlay();
        }

        public override bool ShouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation(UIInterfaceOrientation toInterfaceOrientation)
        {
            // Return true for supported orientations
            return (toInterfaceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientation.PortraitUpsideDown);
        }
    }
}
```

Error in line `RectForMapRect(new MKMapRect())`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This check is a [new feature](http://spouliot.wordpress.com/2012/03/02/linker-vs-bindings-and-ui-thread-checks/) of MonoTouch 5.4. By default the UI thread check is only enabled on **DEBUG** builds. You can, at build-time, manually:

- disable it (on DEBUG) using `--disable-thread-check`; or
- enable it (on Release) using `--force-thread-check`;

You can also turn it on/off at runtime using [`CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls`](http://iosapi.xamarin.com/?link=F%3aMonoTouch.UIKit.UIApplication.CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls).

It's possible that the check is *not* required, Apple documentation on thread safety is not very clear (unlike MSDN). If you find such case (or simply are not sure) then please fill a [bug report](http://bugzilla.xamarin.com).

Comment: I filled a bug report https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=7036 so this can be investigated and, if correct, removed.

Comment: I am getting the same error when calling `CanDrawMapRect`, I have applied the `--disable-thread-check` in the mtouch additional arguments but I keep getting the same exception?

Comment: The option will work only when the linker is enabled (default for device, not for the simulator). You should have a warning in your MonoDevelop's error list pad telling you this. Newer versions of MonoTouch (6.0 iirc) has this check disabled for this API. Otherwise your best bet is using turning off `CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls` before calling your code (and back on again afterward) and use #if DEBUG around them.

Comment: thanks disabling `CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls` did the trick.